# While loop returns only first row value

Tags: php, while-loop

For my tree category I use the below code, but there seems to be a problem, since it returns only the value of the 1st row:

```
<?php
function display_children($parent, $level) { 
    $result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `category` WHERE `parent`='$parent'"); 
    while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) { 
        $title = $row['title'];
        $id = $row['id'];
        $results .= str_repeat('-> ',$level).$title;
        display_children($id, $level+1); 
    } 
    return $results;
}
display_children(0,0); 
?>
```

Any ideas what am I doing wrong and how to fix this?

Comment: Never ever put a `query` inside a loop, or even worse, inside a recursive function. There are 100 ways to do this better.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I see you're not doing anything with your recursive function call return in there. Specifically I think you mean to also add those results to the `$results` variable...

Try this:

```
<?php
function display_children($parent, $level) { 
    $result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `category` WHERE `parent`='$parent'"); 
    $results = '';
    while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) { 
        $title = $row['title'];
        $id = $row['id'];
        $results .= str_repeat('-> ',$level).$title;
        $results .= display_children($id, $level+1); 
    } 
    return $results;
}
echo display_children(0,0); 
?>
```

Additionally I declared the `$results` variable to prevent notices.

Answer (score 2):

Result of your function is lost.
Replace:

```
$results .= str_repeat('-> ',$level).$title;
display_children($id, $level+1);
```

To:

```
$results .= str_repeat('-> ',$level).$title."\n".display_children($id, $level+1);
```

And at the end also display results:

```
echo display_children(0,0);
```